# Assign a multiple numbers to an array

Tags: c

I have a list of number : -1.5 , - 1 , -0,5 , ... , 100.
I want to assign them to an array.
E.g :

```
a[0] = -1.5;
a[1] = -1;
....
a[202] = 100;
```

Can you show me how to do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It looks like what you want to do is what your example does.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate and store the number inside a loop? What have you tried?

Comment: You can edit the question and add sufficient details after which the post can be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to initialize array with several values, you can use [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization):

```
int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

But it should not be used, if you have a lot of numbers. If you need to assign list of numbers, that you stated in question, you should describe them with mathmetical expression in cycle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 203; i++)
{
    a[i] = -1.5 + 0.5 * i;
}
```

If you want to assign array with list of values, that can't be described with mathematical expression, you should read them from [file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).